E-commerce with Flask and postgreSQL (pgAdmin4)
I'm developing a web app for an e-commerce site for academic purposes. It manages the addition and deletion of products by sellers and the purchase of products by buyers.
As for adding a product, I use an upload form like this:
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('area_personale_venditore') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="nomeProdotto" class="form-label">Nome del prodotto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeProdotto" name="nomeProdotto" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="marca" class="form-label">Marca</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" name="marca" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="descrizione" class="form-label">Descrizione</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="descrizione" name="descrizione" rows="3" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="categoria" class="form-label">Categoria</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoria" name="categoria" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="prezzo" class="form-label">Prezzo</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="prezzo" name="prezzo" step="0.01" min="0" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="disponibilita" class="form-label">Disponibilità</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="disponibilita" name="disponibilita" min="0" required>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="foto" class="form-label">Foto del prodotto</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="foto" name="foto" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aggiungi prodotto</button>
</form>

in the last label the seller user should select an image to attribute to the product.
In another file I have a space for displaying cards each containing the image of the product, the name, the brand, the price and its availability:
<div class="row">
    {% for prodotto in prodotti %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ url_for('static', filename=prodotto.foto) }}" alt="Immagine del prodotto">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ prodotto.nomeprod }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Marca: {{ prodotto.marcaprod }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Prezzo: €{{ prodotto.prezzoprod }}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Disponibilità: {{ prodotto.disponprod }}</p>
                <form action="{{ url_for('aggiungi_al_carrello') }}" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="codiceprod" value="{{ prodotto.codiceprod }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aggiungi al carrello</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

My Products table is structured like this:
class Prodotti(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'prodotti'
    codiceprodotto = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    codicevenditore = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('utenti.codiceutente'), nullable=False)
    nomeprod = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    marcaprod = db.Column(db.String(255))
    descrprod = db.Column(db.Text)
    categoria = db.Column(db.String(100))
    prezzoprod = db.Column(db.Float)
    disponprod = db.Column(db.Integer)
    foto = db.Column(db.String(255))

now, I have already created in my app.py file the necessary route to save the image in the database, even looking at the documentation, but it just doesn't want to work, below I paste some parts of the app.py file:
from flask import request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

# some other code here ...

@app.route('/areaPersonaleVenditore', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def area_personale_venditore():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'foto' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['foto']
        # if the user does not select the file, the browser may
        # send an empty file part with no file name
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            # Retrieve data from the form to add a new product
            nome_prodotto = request.form['nomeProdotto']
            marca = request.form['marca']
            descrizione = request.form['descrizione']
            categoria = request.form['categoria']
            prezzo = float(request.form['prezzo'])
            disponibilita = int(request.form['disponibilita'])

            # Retrieve the seller from the session
            nome_utente = session.get('nome_utente')
            venditore = Utenti.query.filter_by(nomeutente=nome_utente, isvenditore=True).first()

            if venditore:
                nuovo_prodotto = Prodotti(
                    codicevenditore=venditore.codiceutente,
                    nomeprod=nome_prodotto,
                    marcaprod=marca,
                    descrprod=descrizione,
                    categoria=categoria,
                    prezzoprod=prezzo,
                    disponprod=disponibilita,
                    foto=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
                )

                try:
                    db.session.add(nuovo_prodotto)
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash('Prodotto aggiunto con successo!', 'success')
                    return redirect(url_for('area_personale_venditore'))
                except IntegrityError as e:
                    db.session.rollback()
                    flash(f"Errore durante l'aggiunta del prodotto: {str(e)}", 'danger')

I hope someone can help me, thanks so much!
Tell me if you need more code!
